# Matlab function number of array element

Tags: matlab

I would be happy to hear somebody explain me the meaning of `1:` before the function below please.

```
yActual = data2_test.Response;
x = 1:numel(yActual)';
```

Comment: MATLAB's [`:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator: _The colon is one of the most useful operators in MATLAB®. It can create vectors, subscript arrays, and specify for iterations._ In your case, see [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html#bvg1wnp-4) example.

Answer (score 0):

A single colon operator in the context of your snippet is a short-hand way of creating a vector:

```
  start_number:end_number
```

equivalent to

```
  [start_number, start_number+1, start_number+2, ...  end_number-1,end_number]
```

In your specific case, the variable x is a vector from 1,2,3... up to the number of elements in data2_test.Response.